# Window not repainting itself after restoring from minimized state

Tags: c, winapi, controls, paint

I'm actually facing a problem with the painting of the WinAPI.

I'm creating my controls like so:

```
case WM_CREATE:
        g_font = CreateFont(16, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ANSI_CHARSET, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, FF_DONTCARE, "MS Dlg Shell");

        g_staticTextToEncrypt = CreateWindowEx(0, "STATIC", "Entrez le texte que vous voulez chiffrer:", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 0, 0, window, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL); SendMessage(g_staticTextToEncrypt, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)g_font, (LPARAM)TRUE);
        g_staticTextAlphabet = CreateWindowEx(0, "STATIC", "Entrez votre alphabet de substitution:", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 0, 0, window, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL); SendMessage(g_staticTextAlphabet, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)g_font, (LPARAM)TRUE);
        g_staticEncryptedText = CreateWindowEx(0, "STATIC", "Message chiffré:", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 0, 0, window, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL); SendMessage(g_staticEncryptedText, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)g_font, (LPARAM)TRUE);

        g_editInputMessage = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_UPPERCASE, 0, 0, 0, 0, window, (HMENU)ID_EDIT_INPUT_MESSAGE, NULL, NULL); SendMessage(g_editInputMessage, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)g_font, (LPARAM)TRUE);
        g_editInputAlphabet = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_UPPERCASE, 0, 0, 0, 0, window, (HMENU)ID_EDIT_INPUT_ALPHABET, NULL, NULL); SendMessage(g_editInputAlphabet, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)g_font, (LPARAM)TRUE);
        g_editOutputEncryptedText = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_CENTER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY, 0, 0, 0, 0, window, (HMENU)ID_EDIT_OUTPUT_ENCRYPTED_TEXT, NULL, NULL); SendMessage(g_editOutputEncryptedText, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)g_font, (LPARAM)TRUE);

        g_buttonCopyEncryptedText = CreateWindowEx(0, "BUTTON", "Copier", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_CENTER, 0, 0, 0, 0, window, ID_BUTTON_COPY_ENCRYPTED_TEXT, NULL, NULL); SendMessage(g_buttonCopyEncryptedText, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)g_font, (LPARAM)TRUE);

        break;
```

and so I can keep them centered even when the window's been resized by the user, I'm handling the WM_PAINT message:

```
case WM_PAINT:
        BeginPaint(window, &ps);

        hdc = GetDC(g_staticTextToEncrypt);
        SelectObject(hdc, g_font);
        GetTextMetrics(hdc, &tm);
        ReleaseDC(g_staticTextToEncrypt, hdc);

        GetWindowRect(window, &windowSize);
        setNewControlsPos(&windowSize, &tm);

        EndPaint(window, &ps);
        break;
```

`setNewControlsPos`is just performing `SetWindowPos(g_staticTextToEncrypt, HWND_BOTTOM, ..., ..., ..., ..., SWP_SHOWWINDOW);` for every control created in WM_CREATE

The problem is that when I minimzed the window and that I restore it, the window is white, every controls have disappeared in the wild. I think that the problem comes from me not repainting the controls in WM_PAINT but only repositionning them but I can't find out how to repaint the controls correctly.

I tried using `RedrawWindow(..., NULL, NULL, RDW_ERASE | RDW_INVALIDATE);` or `InvalidateRect(..., NULL, FALSE);` on every control but it had no effect.

Comment: You should not resize/move child windows in response to `WM_PAINT`. If you are just resizing/moving a child window based on font, then do that once in `WM_CREATE`. Repeat it again if font changes. Also use `SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOZORDER` instead of making them bottom windows.

Comment: Also `GetWindowRect(window, &windowSize);` gives you screen coordinates, these coordinates can go out of client window if you are not careful. You probably want `GetClientRect`

Comment: Handle `WM_SIZE` to reposition your controls when the window size changes. Controls will repaint themselfs, when you move them. You don't need `WM_PAINT` at all. It should only be used for custom painting (e. g. to paint a custom background image), which is not needed here.

Comment: Handling WM_SIZE instead of WM_PAINT fixed the problem. The window properly repaints itself when restored from minimized. Thank you both for your answers.